# Datatables VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have 2 datatables

Table 1 (Type6) has fields: StopNo

Table 2 (StationName) has fields: StopNo, Name

What I want to do is to join the 2 tables, so in sql it would be this:

> SELECT DISTINCT Type6.STOPNO, StationName.NAME FROM Type6 JOIN
>   StationName on StationName.STOPNO=Type6.STOPNO order by NAME"

How do I do this with 2 datatables holding the same information?

Comment: You can do the exact same using Linq - some exmaples: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/656013/linq-join-2-datatables-wildcard ; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688088

Comment: I get StopNo is not a member of System.Data.DataRow

Comment: ... I'll post a solution in a moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

... Let me know if this does the trick...

```
    Dim Result = (From tp6 As DataRow In Type6
             Join stNm As DataRow In StationName
             On tp6.Item("STOPNO") Equals stNm.Item("STOPNO")
             Select x = New With {.STOPNO = tp6.Item("STOPNO"), .NAME = stNm.Item("NAME")}).Distinct
```

Comment: Thanks John, getting there. I used this and then added ComboBox1.DataSource=Result.ToList and i get the following: { STOPNO = S12345, NAME = STATION 1 }. Not sure how I get just "S12345 - STATION 1"

Comment: Managed to sort it by changing the SELECT to:         Select tp6.Item("STOPNO") & " - " & stNm.Item("NAME")).Distinct.                   Thanks again for your help.